# Custom module Cron job on specific time not working

Tags: magento2, cron, crontab

I've written a custom module and the module has to run every Wednesday at 07:10. I've written a cron job and in the schedule. Below is the code added in crontab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
<group id="Vendorname_Modulename"> 
    <job name="Vendorname_Modulename" instance="Netelixir\ProductFeed\Cron\Testcron" method="execute">
        <schedule>00-10 7 * * 3</schedule>
    </job>
 </group>
 </config>
```

The cron job is not working as expected. The cron is working only when it's scheduled to run every minute or 5 minutes or 30 minutes. But not at a particular time. Can anyone help me with this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

First, check the status in the `cron_schedule` table and take the necessary action.

```
SELECT * FROM `cron_schedule` WHERE `job_code` = 'your_cron_job_name'
```

Also, your schedule will be run on ***At every minute from 0 through 10 past hour 7 on Wednesday***. So it will be run 10 times from `2021-07-21 07:00:00` to `2021-07-21 07:10:00`.

[image]

To run **At 07:10 on Wednesday**, we need to use `10 7 * * 3`

[image]

Please check this [link](https://crontab.guru/#00-10_7_*_*_3) to test the schedule.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want the cron to run from 0 to 10 mins at 7 on Wednesday. But it's still not working.

Comment: what is the status of the job on the cron table?

Comment: There are no entries for that job at that time.

Comment: It is probably due to time zone difference and time mismatch.

Comment: I've scheduled the cron job as per the server time stamp.

Comment: Check here Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Locale Options -> Timezone